# Processing Drag-and-Drop Class/Object

Tags: user-interface, drag-and-drop, processing

I'm currently trying to make a class in Processing that allows the user to create objects that can be dragged and dropped. It's not that hard to create individual objects, but I've had some trouble implementing them into a class so that the user can create as many as they wish. Do you have any guidance?

Here is the code I have so far.

`dragndrop.pde`

```
void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
}

void draw() {
  background(80);
  noStroke();
  DragObject d = new DragObject(width/2, height/2, 50, 245);
  d.run();
}
```

`DragObject.pde`

```
class DragObject {
  int x;
  int y;
  int r;
  color col;
  
  DragObject(int xx, int yy, int rr, int c) {
    x = xx;
    y = yy;
    r = rr;
    col = c;
  }
  
  void run() {
    if(mouseX > (x - r/2) && mouseX < (x + r/2) && mouseY > (y - r/2) && mouseY < (y + r/2)) {
      if(mousePressed) {
        x = mouseX;
        y = mouseY;
      } 
    }
    fill(col);
    circle(x, y, r);
  }
}
```

It lets you drag the circle, but only as long as the mouse is within the circle's radius.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will allow you to drag the object around the screen.  In order to have multiple circles you will need to create an object array, eg DragObject[] d; and then initialize it for as many as you want in setup(), eg d = new DragObject[numOfObjects];

```
int xOffset = 0;
int yOffset = 0;

DragObject d;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  d = new DragObject(width/2, height/2, 50, 245);
}

void draw() {
  background(80);
  noStroke();
  d.display();
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (mouseX > (d.x - d.r) && mouseX < (d.x + d.r) && mouseY > (d.y - d.r) && mouseY < (d.y + d.r)) {
    xOffset = mouseX-d.x;
    yOffset = mouseY-d.y;
  }
}

void mouseDragged() {
  d.x = mouseX - xOffset;
  d.y = mouseY - yOffset;
}

class DragObject {
  int x;
  int y;
  int r;
  color col;

  DragObject(int xx, int yy, int rr, int c) {
    x = xx;
    y = yy;
    r = rr;
    col = c;
  }

  void display() {
    fill(col);
    circle(x, y, r);
  }
}
```

**Revision:**
There is an issue in the code above with the method used to determine if the mouse was pressed inside the circle.  The demo above will also move the circle if the mouse is clicked outside (but near) the circle.  A more correct way to determine if the mouse is down inside of the circle is to use Processing's *dist()* function.  To facilitate keeping track of when the mouse is down inside of the circle a *boolean msOver* (mouse over) was added to the object class. There is also a misleading variable label ('r') in the initial class declaration.  I suggest that this be changed to 'diam' (diameter) to reflect the fact that the third parameter of circle() is the width/height and not the radius as the 'r' implies.

A revised (and hopefully improved) demo follows:

```
int xOffset = 0;
int yOffset = 0;

DragObject d;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  d = new DragObject(width/2, height/2, 50, 245);
}

void draw() {
  background(80);
  noStroke();
  d.display();
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (dist(d.x, d.y, mouseX, mouseY) <= d.diam/2) {
    d.msOver = true;
    xOffset = mouseX-d.x;
    yOffset = mouseY-d.y;
    println("inside");
  } else {
    d.msOver = false;
    println("outside");
  }
}

void mouseDragged() {
  if (d.msOver) {
    d.x = mouseX - xOffset;
    d.y = mouseY - yOffset;
  }
}

class DragObject {
  int x, y, diam;
  color col;
  boolean msOver;
  
  DragObject(int xx, int yy, int rr, int c) {
    x = xx;
    y = yy;
    diam = rr;
    col = c;
  }

  void display() {
    fill(col);
    circle(x, y, diam);
  }
}
```

Comment: See revised answer.